# Custom Image Gallery for IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I learned to use iOS default native gallery to select an image with the following code,

```
gallery.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        success: function(event) {
            // set image view
            Ti.API.debug('Our type was: ' + event.mediaType);
            var cropRect = event.cropRect;
            var image = event.media;
            var thumbnail = event.thumbnail;

            console.log('thumbnail:');
        },
        cancel: function() {

        },
        error: function(error) {
        },
        allowEditing:false,
        mediaTypes:[Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
    });


});
```

But i want to create a custom image gallery with the use of grid view, for that, I tried to get the image urls from the iOS camera image gallery. I searched in many websites but I did't find anything that's related to iOS camera image gallery.

Thanks in adavnce........

Can anyone tell me, any modules or links to customize the image gallery by accessing the iOS camera images..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best modules for image gallery access IMHO is Medialibrary Picker 
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3161#!overview
This module lets you access the photos and let the user select multiple.

But for just accessing the photos and thumbnails from image gallery I have also sometimes used iOS Asset Library Access by Marcel Pociot which also is an awesome module:
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1291#!overview

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @Tanel Teemusk the above two links are very useful and it worked for me.